# When building Maven project into Eclipse have errors, also checking maven version after exiting command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to import the tool here as a maven project into Eclipse: https://github.com/EvoSuite/evosuite

It also requires installing M2E plugin (maven integration) for eclipse, but I can't manage to "build" it for some reason and I'm unsure why. Anyone with experience of using maven on java projects know how to build and run this?

Also I'm simply struggling with error after error when trying to install maven and point java home to the right place. Also for some reason I use these commands following my research on path errors with maven / java home:

```
set M2_HOME= C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4
set PATH=%PATH%;%M2_HOME%\bin
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
cmd.exe
mvn -version
```

And for some reason after I do this I can check "mvn -v" and get the right message and run EvoSuite fine by using "maven compile package" when my directory is at the evosuite-master (with the errors on the cmd that I previously showed you in an image), but after I quit the command prompt and go back on it and type "mvn -v" it has the error of "JAVA_HOME not found in your environment" again. It doesn't remember the commands from before.

I can't google a permanent way of setting those commands (pointing JAVA_HOME to jdk). The only answers are from oracle saying set JAVA_HOME in environmental variables to point to JDK but how? It doesn't say what exactly to type and I don't want to mess things up.

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, for setting environment variables, follow [these](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sysdm_advancd_environmnt_addchange_variable.mspx?mfr=true) steps.

For the problem you face while importing the Maven project, please paste in actual error messages. Mostly, the errors are related to unavailability of dependencies and the most probable reason for that is proxy setup if you are in enterprise environment.